# Image picker memory behaviour

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a viewcontroller for sending messages to my backend. It is possible to add an image to the message using the image picker. Once you use the image picker to open the camera or pick a picture from your gallery, the memory usage increases for some mb. after the upload is done, the view controller pops. Deinit is called correctly. But the memory usage won't fall back to the level it was before. it is somewhere in between. You can repeat it, it will always be now around this value.

So it feels like once you use the image picker, iOS keeps it in cache. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe the camera use another process to take photos... As said in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151319/2894160

Comment: @Jochen, There have some memory issues in the image picker may well, and so check the code of it.

Comment: Will the memory increase if you pick the same picture ? If not it means that the image is cached by iOS and it will probably be released. Also make sure you don't keep references to the pickers so they can be deallocated.

Comment: @danypata what do you mean by saying: do not keep references to the pickers? what exactly should i avoid?

Comment: i believe simulator have this behaviour..test on phone it would be fine if there arent any code bugs

Comment: I am debugging on device.